# Edition of a question: how to contact editor?

Tags: discussion

If someone proposes an edition of my question - how can I contact him for discussing a point?

Answer (score 8):

For pending and rejected edits, you cannot directly notify to discuss edits. You can reject with your reason and the user can follow up.

You can always use the main chat room or create a chat room to do this and add it as a comment to the post or for the rejection reason.

Comment: I might add that users who have edited a post can be pinged by the *@username* feature, even though autocomplete does not work for them. Users whose edits are pending or are rejected cannot be pinged like this, though.